# n_classes * n_clusters_per_class must be smaller or equal 2 in make_classification function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am generating datas on Python by this command line :

```
X, Y = sklearn.datasets.make_classification(n_classes=3  ,n_features=20, n_redundant=0, n_informative=1,
                         n_clusters_per_class=1)
```

but I get this error and can't understand what to do to avoid...:

> ValueError: n_classes * n_clusters_per_class must be smaller or equal 2 ** n_informative

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc string says that the clusters are placed on the corners of a hypercube. A hypercube for n=1 is the unit line segment. Which has 2 corner points. Thus only 2 clusters can be placed. This is only an algorithmic constraint

Answer (score 2):

Note the below rule should be followed:

> (n_classes * n_clusters_per_class) ≤ (2 ^ n_informative)

As per post, eqn becomes:
(3 x 1) ≤ (2 ^ 1)

The above is wrong, eqn doesn't satisfy. So one option is to increase n_informative to 2, and then it will satisfy.

For meaning of the parameters, you can follow the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can increase n_informative to 2.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it works but I don't understand why there is that constraint, do you?